# How to read and write objects into SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

My first table is `Clinics` with columns:

```
ClinicId, ClinicName, ClinicShortName
```

My second table is `Employees` with columns:

```
EmployeeId, EmployeeName, ClinicId, OnJob
```

I also have a view `v_employees` defined as:

```
SELECT   
    Employees.EmployeeId, Employees.EmployeeName, 
    Clinics.ClinicShortName, 
    Employees.OnJob
FROM     
    Clinics 
INNER JOIN
    Employees ON Clinics.ClinicId = Employees.ClinicId
```

And my C# code is:

```
class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmpolyeeName { get; set; }
    public int ClinicId { get; set; }
    public bool OnJob { get; set; }
}

class Clinic
{
    public int ClinicId { get; set; }
    public string ClinicName { get; set; }
    public string ClinicShortName { get; set; }
}

List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();

private void InitEmployees()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(......);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from v_employees", con );
    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee()
            {
                EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EmployeeId"]),
                EmpolyeeName = dr["EmployeeName"].ToString(),
                // how to use ClinicShortName field in this position?
                // Because I want the data to be displayed into DataGridView control.
                OnJob = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["OnJob"])
            };

        employeeList.Add(employee);
    }

    dr.Close();
    con.Close();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = employeeList;
}
```

How could I import objects into SQL Server?

Should I use the `List<T>` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a field of `ClinicShortName` into `employee` class but why not use sqladapter? it generates columns according to the data returned

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(......);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from v_employees", con );
    con.Open();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    adapter.Fill(table);
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I want use another method.